# how can I purge all pending extrinsics in the transaction pool

Tags: parachain, extrinsic, stalled

I suspect that an extrinsic caused the block production to stall. It's status remains at "broadcast" and no new blocks will be produced. To be sure I'd like to remove it from the tx pool on all nodes/collators. How can I do that?

I did find the rpc `author_removeExtrinsic` which should remove and ban an extrinsic by hash. But how would I learn the hash of my extrinsic? if I call `author_pendingExtrinsics` I get the decoded extrinsic, not the hash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`author_removeExtrinsic` support remove extrinsic by value

[image]

You can also either write a script to calculate the hash, or just read it from polkadot apps under Network -> Node info page

[image]

Comment: Yes. We used to create a script to remove some problematic transactions from the collator txpool periodically

Comment: Hi @h4x3rotab, is it fine If I ask for the script? We currently encounter the same problem because we're batching nonces from an account.